# Passing String scope variables as arguments to $http.get in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What is wrong with the http request statement in given code:

```
$scope.s ="api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=pilani,in";

 $http.get($scope.s)
.success(function (data)
{       
alert("temp");
    angular.element('#temperature').scope().temp = data;
    angular.element('#temperature').scope().$apply();
});
```

This http request isn't working.

Comment: I think you missed to add protocol to your url..Either `http` or `https`

Comment: Maybe the cross domain policy prohibits the desired request.

Comment: Add an error handler with `.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {})`. But you probably need to add *http://* to you request URL.

Comment: The control isn't going to http request-success, so no data collected and no output shown. I haven't checked in console

Comment: Yes! Adding the "http://" to url- is giving results.Thanks @AlexanderWallin

Comment: @AarushiMishra I think it was suggested by me in the 1st place :p

Comment: Sorry- thanks to @pankajparkar also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the protocol part of the URL. When you pass a URL without a protocol to `$http.get` (or more generally to `XMLHttpRequest.open`) it is treated as a relative URL to the current path.

Add `http://` to the start of the URL and it should work as expected, since the server allows cross origin requests. Note that since this server is not secure users might get a "mixed content" warning if you're making these requests from an `https://` address.